# Dimensional analysis physics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, units, dimensional-analysis, si-units

In a certain system, the units of length, mass and
time are chosen to be 1 cm, 100 g and 10 s. The
unit of kinetic energy according to above sys-
tem of unit, will be N erg. Find the value of N.

I did it like this

10^7 erg=N ( (100g×cm^2)/10^2 s^2
10^7 erg  =N (g cm^2)/s^2
So N=10^7
But answer is 1

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because not really a question about physics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erg is the energy unit in cm-g-s system.

So $1$ (their kinetic energy unit)$=100$g $\times$ ($1$cm$ / 10$s)$^2 = 1$ g $\times$ (cm/s)$^2=1$ erg

So $N=1$.